# order with recent created record in multiple associated models rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i have three associated models

## artical.rb:

```
 has_many :texts
 has_many :notes
 has_many :attachments
```

i want to order artical with recent created record

```
artical 6 = text: 20 dec , note: 19 dec, attachment: 20dec
artical 9 = text: 18 dec , note: 21 dec, attachment: not present 
artical 10 = text: not present , note: 30 dec, attachment: not present
```

Order will Be depending on text,note,attachment the atrical which has new note,text or attachment will be on the top:

```
 ###artical Index Page 

 artical 10
 artical 9 
 artical 6
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using [`order`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order)?:

```
Artical.includes(:attachments).order('attachments.created_at DESC')
```

Comment: I think he wants to order `Artical` by any of `Artical.texts.created_at`, `Artical.notes.created_at`, or `Artical.attachments.created_at`, not `Artical.created_at`.

Comment: @coreyward : Initially I thought the same thing, but OP states in "order will be" section that the order needs to be on artical without specifying that it will also be depending on texts, notes, or attachments. However, that is also possible by simply eager loading associations and using the table names in order method.

Comment: @coreyward you are right i want artical to sort according to text,note or attachment's created_at field means, as in question artical 10 is on top because it has a note which has more recent date than others

Comment: @Surya This still only sorts by `attachments.created_at`, whereas Sahil wants to sort by the most recent `created_at` date for any of `roles`, `texts`, or `attachments`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options. One is to join all three associated tables, and use the date functions in your RDBMS (e.g. Postgresql) to [determine the latest of the associated `created_at` dates for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152368/sql-calculating-the-max-date-across-multiple-tables) of the `articals` table. Depending on your scenario, that might be what you have to do.

If it were me, I'd add a `assoc_updated_at` column to `articals` and use the [touch](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-touch) in `ActiveRecord` to bump the timestamp anytime one of the associations was updated, then order by that column:

```
class Text
  belongs_to :artical, touch: :assoc_updated_at
end

Artical.order(assoc_updated_at: :desc)
```